# get weekdays dates in a month

Tags: php, arrays, date, days

Ok so currently I am doing this by hand

```
$days= array('2013-06-03','2013-06-04','2013-06-05','2013-06-06','2013-06-07','2013-06-11','2013-06-12','2013-06-13','2013-06-14','2013-06-17','2013-06-18','2013-06-19','2013-06-20','2013-06-21','2013-06-24','2013-06-25','2013-06-26','2013-06-27','2013-06-28',);
```

But I want to move it to an automotive way where the user selects the month and the PHP script generates the weekday dates.

If anyone has see away to do this in the past that would be great.

I still will need to find away to not include public holidays (based on Melbourne Australia Public Holidays).

But thought I would still ask the question as we have more weekdays than public holidays :)

Comment: On my phone so not going to write any code.  But look into PHPs DateTime objects.  They are smart enough to know the day of the week.  So you can loop through adding a day and checking if it is a weekday or not.  Then you can cross reference it with an public holiday API.

Comment: Not sure why this would get down voted, because it is an important question be it, for me or another person in the future

Answer (score 0):

The function `strftime` converts a timestamp to the name of the weekday with the format "%A".
http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php

```
$timestamp=mktime(0, 0, 0, 6, 3, 2013);
$day=strftime("%A", $timestamp);
```

`$day` will contain `"Monday"` after this code. You can now easily iterate through all days with `mktime` and then check the weekday.

Answer (score 0):

```
$month = 10;

for ($i = 1; $i <= 31; $i++) { 
    $timestamp = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $i, 2012);
    if (date("n", $timestamp) == $month) {
        $day = date("N", $timestamp);
        if ($day == 1 OR $day <= 5) {
            $days[$day][] = date("D", $timestamp);
        }
    }
}
```

//print $days